# Adding a letter to the name of an object

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a series of pairs text fields that are pragmatically added, one is called 0_1 and the other is called 0_1w. I am wanting todo something to 0_1w when an event happens (keypress) to 0_1, and the same with 0_2, 0_3 etc...

Is it possible to just grab the sender for the keypress event and append the letter w to the end of it or is there any simple way I can do what I need with the w text field from within the other text field.

Thanks

Comment: does "text field" mean TextBox control?  are you really wanting to rename objects or change the text property?  Please show the code you are trying to make work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each control has a `Name` property, so if you cast the sender to `Control`, you'll be able to get that name string.  You can then append "w" to it and look for another control with that name.  You can look up controls by name using the `Controls` collection on the form.

```
Dim senderName As String = DirectCast(sender, Control).Name
Dim pairedName As String = senderName & "w"
Dim paired As Control = Me.Controls(pairedName)
```

However, the form's `Controls` collection only contains the controls that are directly added to it.  If the sender is inside a container control, such as a `Panel`, only that panel control will be included in the form's `Controls` collection.  In a case like that, you'd need to look at the panel's `Controls` collection.  Therefore, since the two paired controls are probably inside the same container control, it would be safer to do this:

```
Dim paired As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control).Parent.Controls(pairedName)
```